# Deploying C++ game in Linux

Tags: linux, deployment

I am indie game developer working on Windows platform, but I have actually little to none experience with Linux and deploying apps for it. I am polishing my game written in C++'11 based on SDL 2.0 with several other cross-platform dependencies (like AngelScript or PugiXML) on Windows and I want to distribute it over Linux too and have a few question about that. The game is commercial, closed source which is currently on Steam's GreenLite, but I want to distribute free alpha version downloadable from my website regardless of GreenLite status.

1.) Are the main Linux distributions ABI (application binary interface) compatible? Or do I need to compile my game on every supported distribution/platform?

2.) If so, which distributions/platforms are reasonable choices to support?

3.) What is the best way to install an app and it's dependencies on Linux? I've read about deb and rpm systems, but it's still confusing - is there any way to automatically generate setup packages for various distributions?

4.) How does Steam work with Linux? How should I prepare my app for distribution via it?

Excuse me if I ask wrong questions, the whole world of Linux is pretty new to me and I got lost reading various articles and manual pages...

Comment: Sorry to reopen this, but have you ever been able to do a solid Linux release? I am trying to do the same and I am struggling with the different glibc versions on the different distros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This depends on what the distribution is derived from. Generally, there's no need to recompile a program on something like Ubuntu under Fedora so long as the code remains unchanged. Since Ubuntu and Fedora would have to be using the same libraries (albeit in different locations perhaps) and anything OpenGL-related would be a driver issue; therefore it is hardly a requirement to recompile your software. I would be extremely surprised if you had to recompile your software since all distros use pretty much the same set of libraries/got bash/use the Linux kernel but have different package managers. The last part is where it gets complex:
2. The aforesaid distributions have different package managers which requires you to repackage your software accordingly. You could release pre-compiled binaries under a tar.gz file and simply have distro maintainers package the software for you; though if you want to control how your software is distributed then you should better do that yourself. Because of this issue surrounding the many package managers out there, people still resort to recompiling source code through a make file which can be generated through cmake. This only happens if certain dependencies are, for whatever reason, 'renamed' in which case because of a simple name change the program magically doesn't find the dependency. Since there's also no naming convention it even makes life harder. The most important virtue here is Trust, and Trust therein to have developers follow naming conventions so everyone can reference the same package of the same name.

The best distros to support are the most popular ones: Ubuntu and openSUSE would be great starting points. Linux Mint, Fedora and Red Hat and Debian use package managers likewise of the aforesaid.

3. Meanwhile, you should know that you can't statically link GPL'd code in your software without also making your software also GPL. A way to work round this is to resolve dependencies by either: A. Including the relevant dependencies in the same folder as the executable (much like *.dlls on Windows) or to depend on the system upon which your program is run to look inside the same directories your program looked into while compiling and linking. The latter is actually riskier since it bears the assumption the user will have the libraries and unmodified. The former will make your overall software use less storage, but including the dependencies would only mean increasing the size of your package but ensures consistency across all systems.

As for installation, you would need a bash executable that moves the contents of your directory to the right locations. Generally, the main app goes into /usr/bin and any app-related data goes into the home folder. This again depends on the distro; look for a .local directory, or you could create a directory dedicated to your app that is hidden. Hidden folders are prefixed with a period. Why put this stuff in the home folder, and what? The why: because the home folder gives read-and-write permissions to everyone by default. The what: anything that needs to be run with the app without the user having to authorise it. Dependencies should thus be located in the home folder, preferably under your own directory. Different conventions follow; some may disagree with me on this one.

You might also want to use steam's API which does most of this work for you. Under Steam, your app may be under steam's own directory and thus functions as a steam APP with all the functionality therein.

http://www.steampowered.com/steamworks/

To find out more about how to get your app on steam. I have to say I was really impressed, and they even include code samples. The best part is that this API is on Linux as well. I don't know much apart from that Steam would be handling the execution of your app through its own layer. Wherein, there's no need to independently distribute your app the previous steps.

Note that you can also distribute your software through the Ubuntu Software Centre if you are interested.

http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/

Though, Ubuntu has more focus on getting apps running regardless of platform.

Know that Linux has no single convention, but its convention is simply derived from pragmatism, not by theory. At the end of the day, how you want your software run on Linux is up to you.

Comment: Thank you, this is by far the best answer here - just one more question: if I store dependencies in `home` directory, then will they be available for all users? Should the assets be stored in `home` as well?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a game developer and I come from open source community so can't really advise on delivering binaries. I'll try to answer some of your questions though:

Valve has a steam runtime you can target on linux (https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-runtime) - this would be the best way to port your game. I saw it mentioned in one of their Linux dev videos on youtube my understanding is it bundle a bunch of libraries inclding SDL and it is setup to emulate a specific version of ubuntu. So if you write your game against the steam runtime it will run in any linux distro that steam has been ported too.

As for natively packaging your game one thing to consider is if you package it as a deb or RPM and instruct it to depend on distro provided libraies than your app may break when the libraries are updated (some distros update libs quite often - others are more stable). Dynamically linking against system libraries works well for open source since people can patch the code when libraies change not ideal for close sourced stuff.

You can statically link your binary at build time, which means you have a larger sized binary. But than you don't have to worry about app breaking when libs are updated.

Some programs like Chrome bundle their own libs (which are essentially forks of the system libs) again this makes download size much larger but also has potential to cause security problems, people tend to frown on this. (see: http://lwn.net/Articles/378865/)

Comment: I just can't statically link everything, because some of my dependencies are under GPL

Comment: You can probably bundle the libs (But you'd need to supply source code for the GPL'd libs you bundle - or at least link to the source). Or you can dynamically link to the system libs and accept breakage may occur at some point in future. The cynic in me suspects it would be much easier if you were to open source your game - you are already using open source libraries after all.

Comment: @PiotrK if your libs are GPL your code is now too; you can link to LGPL code without making your code open but GPL code *requires* your code also be GPL (or you reach an alternative licensing arrangement with the authors of the libs).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This is not true, as long as GPL code is linked in shared object (or DLL in Windows), not into main executable itself.

Comment: @PiotrK Ask your lawyer. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Libraries) says *This key dispute is whether or not non-GPL software can legally statically link or dynamically link to GPL libraries. Different opinions exist on this issue. **The GPL is clear in requiring that all derivative works of code under the GPL must themselves be under the GPL**.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oh, I see, I thought that matter was settled (at least in my country which is Poland) - but I found out that it is not. Fortunately my only GPL dependency is not a deal breaker, I can live without it.

Comment: @PiotrK There's probably a BSD version around, but yeah there's a reason the BSD guys do things like [libedit](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/) instead of using readline.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah, and still someone dares to call GPL "free as in free speech"... Virus-like licenses are pain in the neck, they definitely don't imply freedom. I've supported and contributed a few Open Source projects in the past, releasing my code on X11/BSD-like licenses. I just don't get the "freedom" behind GPL. This is not intended as flame war igniter, thanks in advance...

Comment: @PiotrK To be fair, no one makes you drink GPL beer. They just require that if you include anything from a GPL beer in your beer that it also be GPL. Free beer is best beer.

Comment: I completely disagree with your attitude about the GPL it is "free as in speech" and just like how in some countries they have a consitution to protect free speech, GPL has a license to protect software freedom.

If I write a library (or any other code) and release it under the GPL and you find it useful enough to use my code then its only fair I'm able to take your modified code myself. So maybe for you its a virus to me its a feature.

Answer (score 1):

1.) No, ABIs of main Linux distributions are not fully compatible. In a narrow sense, they are *mostly* compatible. But in a broader sense, there are many differences in which some elements of the system work, are configured, etc.., OTOH, making "packages" is not a big problem *per* *se*, just some work. Also, what works for a "major" distribution (like Debian) works (pretty much always) on all derivatives (like Ubuntu, Mint...).

2.) A good start list to support is: Debian (.deb), RedHat and Fedora (.rpm both). Their package formats and tools are mature and well known. This will "cover" a lot of derivatives.

3.) There are some "cross-distribution" package builders, but are mostly not up for the task. Writing a definition script for most of package formats is not hard, once you get a hang of it. Also, some commercial tools have "Installation script generators" for Linux which take care of things for you (they don't generate .deb or .rpm, rather a complex shell script, similar to a Windows EXE installer)

4.) Sorry, I don't know much about Steam. O:)

So, from my experience, the best way to do it is to accept the ugly truth that you have to select a few major distributions *and* their versions ('cause things can change very much between versions) and make packages for them, and test often on all of them. And be happy that you're not developing some long-lived kernel module/driver, because if you add tracking kernel API changes to the whole picture... :)