# How to properly release C++ software (game) on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, deployment, glibc

I have created a small test game (Pacman-clone) with my newly self-created 2D/3D game engine. I have not used any IDE to create this, but only used vim and premake5 to create the Makefile. The only dependency I have is SDL2 for window creation/events and OpenGL for rendering. So I am not using any framework like Unity, Qt, ...

The game is supposed to be commercial and closed source, otherwise I would distribute the source and maybe create some packages like .deb and things like that. But this is not an option. It should be delivered as is in binary and not require the user to install other packages.

Suppose I want to release this game to the public, say like on GOG or Steam or something (it's not my intention with this test game, but it could be in the future with something else). How do I release it properly?

I have tried the following: I created a VM with the latest Ubuntu (minimal installation) on it (as Ubuntu is usually the OS that is supported by Linux games) and I copied my compiled executable on it. I started it and got notification of missing libraries. I added the libraries (so-files from my Arch Linux where I built the executable) to the same directory and set the library path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. to include the current directory. I created a start.sh script that starts the game in a oneliner including this setting.

And it worked on my machine, so I passed it on to someone using Linux Mint. He was unable to start it because he got "GLIBC_2.29 not found". I don't know if it's possible to pass my version of GLIBC.

I guess that my Arch Linux (where I created the executable) comes with a newer version of GLIBC than he has.

So, how do you solve this? Or am I completely going wrong with this procedure and should I do it differently?

Edit: I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27029729/deploying-c-game-in-linux?rq=1) which seems to agree with the method I am using, but there is no mention about the issues I encounter with for example glibc.

Edit: Lots of games on Steam/GOG/Itch run native on Linux (and I am not talking about the Mono games and those that use wine internally). I can play them on Arch, Mint, ... without issues. They don't seem to have problems with licenses either.

Edit: I am thankful for the links to managed app stores and things like that that manage the software and they are certainly worth thinking about, but I don't like the fact that I need some kind of account (with a license agreement no doubt and maybe costs at some point) while I have games in my Steam and GOG library that run natively on any Linux distro I have without all of that.

Comment: Be aware that as a licensee of GPL code, you can only distribute it under the terms of the license.

Comment: This is one of the core reasons why Linux has such a struggle to achieve relevance. On Windows, it's trivial to build for Windows 7 even if you yourself have Windows 10 or even Windows Server. Visual Studio just doesn't care. On Ubuntu version X.Y, you build for Ubuntu version X.Y, as you noticed. In this case, the conflict was in Glibc, but there are dozens of other possible dependencies. Glibc is one of the worst offenders, as it is a system library. You cannot replace Mint's version of Glibc with your Ubuntu version. With other libs you technically can, but then the license is a problem.

Comment: I don't have in depth knowledge of the license stuff. I am quite sure SDL2 is free to use for whatever you want. Other games get released on Steam, GOG and Itch working fine on Linux (X4 uses SDL2), so how do they work out the license issues, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work and I think is also used by other games on Steam/GOG/Itch that do not use wine/mono/... to just make their windows game work on Linux.

I installed Ubuntu 18 (or 16 if you prefer it to work on older OSses too) and set up my build environment there (I had to rewrite some of my C++ code because not all new C++ conventions are available yet). Then I installed another Ubuntu 18 machine and started the executable there. It told me which libraries it was missing and I manually added every one of them from my build-Ubuntu 18. After that, my game worked.

Then I installed Linux Mint 19 and hooray... it worked!

Then I ran the executable on Ubuntu 20 and Arch Linux (latest update) and it needed another lib that I also got from my build-Ubuntu 18, and it worked.

I passed on the executable to someone else and it worked fine on his Linux machine too...

What I mean is: if I build it for the lowest version of glibc, it seems to work fine on newer systems too.

This may not be the most waterproof system out there, but at least, like with almost all other games on Steam/GOG, I can now say that the game will run on Ubuntu 18, Ubuntu 20 and know that it also works on several other distro's.

And I don't need any third party tool like Flatpak and Snapcraft. I may still end up using them for supporting their good cause and also because it helps spread my game as well. But then, I will first need to finish my real game of course...

I am marking this as the solution as long as nobody is able to give me a better one without me creating accounts on third party services.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Flatpak?

It allows you to package your game with all the required dependencies.

Plus with the added benefit that everyone gets to run your game on the same runtime environment irrespective of what Linux distro they choose. So you won't encounter this type of situation...

> I guess that my Arch Linux (where I created the executable) comes with a newer version of GLIBC than he has.

Comment: This certainly looks interesting. I will look into this more in depth and I hope it allows me to do whatever I want and doesn't limit my commercial freedom and things like that.

Comment: @scippie flathub (official flatpak apps hosting repository) encourages commercial apps on their platform too :) I noticed there are games available that are proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io).  Though it generally focuses on Ubuntu-based distros, it has generally good compatibility with others as well.  It also has a [tutorial for packaging apps in C++](https://snapcraft.io/first-snap/c), which could be useful.  Though snaps are generally distributed via the Snap Store, you could theoretically distribute them standalone.

Comment: Like Flatpak, this looks interesting, and I will look into it, but it requires you have an account and some kind of license to agree to and I would like to be able to prevent that.